# Capture / redirect all output of ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, subprocess, process-pool

I am trying to capture all output from a `ProcessPoolExecutor`.

Imagine you have a file `func.py`:

```py
print("imported")  # I do not want this print in subprocesses

def f(x):
    return x
```

then you run that function with a `ProcessPoolExecutor` like

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from func import f  # ⚠️ the import will print! ⚠️

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as ex:  # ⚠️ the import will happen here again and print! ⚠️
        futs = [ex.submit(f, i) for i in range(15)]
        for fut in futs:
            fut.result()
```

Now I can capture the output of the first import using e.g., `contextlib.redirect_stdout`, however, I want to capture all output from the subprocesses too and redirect them to the stdout of the main process.

In my real use case, I get warnings that I want to capture, but a simple print reproduces the problem.

This is relevant to prevent the following bug https://github.com/Textualize/rich/issues/2371.